# Meteor tracker skips unexpectedly

Tags: meteor, meteor-tracker

I am following a tutorial about Tracker and seeing an unexpected behavior.

Here, I am using a getter and a setter to see that `Tracker.autorun()` is called whenever I call the setter.

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  var favoriteFood = 'Apples';
  var favoriteFoodDep = new Tracker.Dependency;

  var getFavoriteFood = function () {
    favoriteFoodDep.depend();
    return favoriteFood;
  };

  var setFavoriteFood = function (newValue) {
    favoriteFood = newValue;
    favoriteFoodDep.changed();
  };

  var handle = Tracker.autorun (function () {
    console.log("your favorite food is " + getFavoriteFood());
  });

  setFavoriteFood("Mangos");
  setFavoriteFood("Bananas");
  setFavoriteFood("Cheese");
}
```

When I open my browser console, I expect to see

```
Your favorite food is Apples
Your favorite food is Mangos
Your favorite food is Bananas
Your favorite food is Cheese
```

But All I see is the first and the last one, no matter how many calls I make for `setFavoriteFood()`.

```
Your favorite food is Apples
Your favorite food is Cheese
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess that there is a race condition here.  Because it executes the lines

```
setFavoriteFood("Mangos");
setFavoriteFood("Bananas");
setFavoriteFood("Cheese");
```

.. so quickly, by the time the getter re-runs the invalidated computation, the set value is "Cheese".

To test this, consider running the following:

```
setFavoriteFood("Mangos");
window.setTimeout(function() { 
  setFavoriteFood("Bananas");
}, 1000);
window.setTimeout(function() { 
  setFavoriteFood("Cheese");
}, 2000);
```

I suspect that it will log all 4 to the console.  Report back and let me know!

Comment: It was a race condition like you said. I wonder if this is trivial or has a broader implication..

Comment: @MikeC - I don't think its an issue in this case, because I don't think that the client would even be able to process updates that quickly.  Tracker.Dependency is really useful for updating your templates when data sources change.  Also, be sure to check out ReactiveVars - really simple wrapping of a variable with a tracker, depending on get and invalidating on set http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/reactivevar_pkg